# How to make horizontal line stop at specific x-value?

Tags: python, matplotlib, horizontal-line

I would like to draw a horizontal line with matplotlib's `plt.axhline()` function, but I want the horizontal line to stop at the absolute value of 5 on the x-axis. How do I set `xmax` in `plt.axhline()` to stop at 5?

```
plt.figure()
plt.plot(np.arange(-60, 60, 20), np.arange(0, 1.2, 0.2))
plt.axhline(y = 0.5, xmax = 5, c= 'r')
```

Comment: `plt.axhlines` takes `xmin` and `xmax` in axes coordinates. If you want to use data coordinates, you could use [`plt.hlines`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hlines.html#matplotlib.pyplot.hlines) instead

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `plt.hlines` instead, also specify a `xmin` and change `c` to `color` .

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
xmin = -65
plt.figure()
plt.plot(np.arange(-60, 60, 20), np.arange(0, 1.2, 0.2))
plt.hlines(y = 0.5, xmin=xmin , xmax = 5, color= 'r')
plt.xlim(left=xmin);
```

Comment: How do I make the horizontal line meet the y-axis, because now it stops at -60?

Comment: I have updated my answer with `plt.xlim`